# Should you dispose a new object parameter in a method?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

The following method assigns a clone of the bitmap to a local bitmap variable in the class. The second parameter tells whether to dispose of the source bitmap after the assignment, as a matter of convenience.

```
Public Sub setBitmap(ByRef SourceBitmap As Bitmap, DisposeSource As Boolean)
uBitmap = SourceBitmap.Clone
If DisposeSource AndAlso SourceBitmap IsNot Nothing Then
  SourceBitmap.Dispose()
  SourceBitmap = Nothing
  end if
End Sub
```

Should the source bitmap be disposed when it's a new bitmap? In other words, should the second parameter be True or False in this example?

```
mView.setBitmap(New Bitmap(2000, 2000, pFormat), False)
```

How about when it's a new bitmap returned from another function?

```
rview.setBitmap(readThumbnail(...), False)
```

Comment: depends really on your business logic/domain. you should always dispose right up to the point of when you are completely done with the object In question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new bitmap in the call, you should make the method dispose it:

```
mView.setBitmap(New Bitmap(2000, 2000, pFormat), True)
```

Each disposable object that you create should be disposed, and as you don't keep a reference to it, the only chance to get it disposed is to make the method do it.

The same goes if you use a method to create the bitmap. If you don't keep a reference to it so that you can dispose it, the method has to do it.

If you create a bitmap and keep the reference to it so that you can dispose it later, you can send `False` as the second parameter:

```
Dim img As New Bitmap(2000, 2000, pFormat)
mView.setBitmap(img, False)
' ...
img.Dispose()
```

Generally you would use the form where you send `False` as the second parameter. It's easier to follow code if the level creating the object is also responsible for disposing it. The code for ensuring that it works properly can also be written simpler (for example using the `Using` keyword to ensure that an object is disposed).

Comment: If an exception is thrown between New Bitmap() and .Dispose(), there will be a resource leak. The Using block prevents this.

Comment: @glenebob: Yes, but a `Using` block is not the only possible way to do that.

Comment: No, not the only way, but generally (and in this case) the simplest way. Another, wordier option is to wrap the code that may fail in a try/finally, and put the .Dispose() in the finally block - which is what a Using block is under the hood.

Answer (score 5):

Disposing a caller's object is generally bad form. Personally, I would remove that functionality altogether. This would be more correct:

```
using newBitmap As New Bitmap(2000, 2000, pFormat)
    mView.setBitmap(newBitmap)
end using
```